# how to create a field in django that is only enabled after filling in the previous one?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I want to enable in django admin the "registration" field only if "bond" is filled in as "outsourced".

```
class Contato(models.Model):

    BOND_CHOICES = (
        ('server', 'Servidor'),
        ('outsourced', 'Terceirizado'),
        ('trainee', 'Estagiário'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nome', max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Data de Nascimento')
    email = models.CharField(verbose_name='Email', max_length=100)
    branchLine = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Ramal', max_digits=4, decimal_places=0)
    bond = models.CharField(verbose_name='Vínculo', max_length=10, choices=BOND_CHOICES)
    registration = models.CharField(verbose_name='Matrícula', max_length=20)
```

Comment: You'll need to use Javascript, there's nothing you can do server-side to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use javascript to make this works. In this example I used `Django admin jQuery`. And make sure to add this js file in ModelAdmin

admin.py

```
class ContatoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:
        js = ['/static/admin/js/admin-registration.js']
```

I have created `admin-registration.js` in `static` > `admin` > `js` folder.

```
django.jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    django.jQuery('#id_registration').attr('readonly', true)
    django.jQuery('#id_bond').click(function(event) {
        if ( event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].text == 'Terceirizado') {
            django.jQuery('#id_registration').attr('readonly', false)
        }
    })
})
```